# DllImport("user32.dll") not working in Hosted IIS (Windows.Forms.SendKeys)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have web api developed in asp.net 4.0 . Here i am trying to send data from my api service(hosted in IIS) to another application(local machine). Its working fine while i used to run the application in visual studio development server but getting access denied issue while running from IIS. Because it is not able to find Active Windows. Below is my code.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult TextSimulation(string InputText, string ApplicationName)
    {
        DataAccessDAL objClsData = new DataAccessDAL();
        OleDbDataReader _SqlReader;

        try
        {
            int iHandle = NativeWin32.FindWindow(null, ApplicationName);
            NativeWin32.SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);

            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(InputText);

            return Ok("OK");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ExceptionLog.SendExcepToDB(ex, "ConsReg", "GetconsDetails");
            return Ok(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            objClsData._Connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you try setting "LoadUserProfile" to `true` for the AppPool your app is running in? (this solves more problems than expected, at least for me)

Comment: @Alex tried "LoadUserProfile" to true. but it is not working

Comment: I thought services didnt interact with GUIs - hence you cant display winforms etc from one.

Comment: `SendKeys` sends data to application on the same machine. Of course it doesn't work when the server is on a different machine. The server code runs on the server, not in the browser.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't going to work. The C# code you're writing is running on the *server*, which will usually be locked in a server room and not have anyone logged onto it interactively at all. Be clear in your head that there is a difference between the *client* (where the browser is) and the *server*, and things you assume are true when *one machine is acting in both roles* aren't generally true.

Comment: But While this runs perfectly while debugging web api in Visual studio

Comment: Because when you're running the server in Visual Studio, the server and your "local application" run on the same machine. Not to mention that the development server usually has far higher priviledges and runs as an interactive application, not a server.

Comment: @Luaan If host the api in same machine and access through postman from same machine then it wont work?

Comment: @Pradees - if you continue to use the VS development server/IIS express where the server code continues to run *in your interactive session* then it will appear to work. When you run it in full-blown IIS where it's running under a different identity and not attached to your interactive session, it will not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is there any alternative solution for this?

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to do. The solution you're choosing to do it isn't going to work, you need a different approach. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not if your goal is that your website, running in a browser, starts interacting with other windows on that client machine. That's just not how the web works. On the other hand, if you *are* trying to interact with something on the server side, look for *programmatic* ways of interacting with that program and a way to run it without any windows.

Comment: We are developing an Android application. The android device is connect to pc through USB Tehernet(Its a requirement from client), then communicate with the pc. When user type in mobile keyboard, I need to send these text values to pc. Also mobile user can select in which pc window the texts should appear. - Thats the requirement ;)

Comment: When I connect the mobile with pc through usb tethernet, I will get the IP address and can trigger the webservices that hosted on the same machine. Thats what I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated!